# How to take the backup of AWS NVMe block devices

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have recently purchased AWS E2 instance "m5ad.4xlarge", which has 3 disks out of which two are 300 GB NVMe SSD drives.

Now the problem is, these two disks are not available in AWS Volumes section and hence I am unable to trigger the snapshot for these volumes.

In the below screen shot if you would notice that I have total 3 volumes. The first disk nvme0n1 which is mounted as root is only visible in AWS volume section but other two disks nvme1n1 and nvme2n1 are not visible in AWS volumes section. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make and attach ebs volume for backup, and rsync data to it by cron.

Or, you can send all data from nvme to s3/glacier also by cron, and attach lificycle policy to bucket.

Comment: this would be a very time consuming task.